# How to extract substrings with a known structure from a filename in Unix?

Tags: awk, grep

I've got a bunch of complex filenames containing a lot of infos and I'm trying to extract two substrings from each filename.

Names have this structure:

```
ADNI_002_S_0295_MR_MT1__N3m_Br_20110623105302806_S110476_I241350_RightHippoSubfields.mgz.txt
ADNI_002_S_1155_MR_MT1__GradWarp__N3m_Br_20120322164018368_S97230_I291880_RightHippoSubfields.mgz.txt
ADNI_002_S_0729_MR_MT1__N3m_Br_20120913163818876_S159861_I334105_RightHippoSubfields.mgz.txt
```

From each filename, I'd like to extract in the Unix shell:

1. the string in the form `???_S_????` (like `002_S_0295`, `002_S_115`, `002_S_0729`)
2. and the number enclosed between `_I` and the next underscore (like `241350`, `291880`, `334105`)

I've tried some combinations of grep and awk, but really I can't come up with a solution.

Comment: Please show exactly what output you want.  Do you want the two parts of each name in two variables, or in a single string? With a character separating the parts?  Etc.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) — a key part of that is the required output.  Another key part is showing your best effort.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had included all the required elements but I was wrong. Thanks for your suggestions, I'll be more careful and thorough when asking again in the future.

Comment: It's not too late to add the missing information to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store the file names in a file `file` you can do:

> 1.- the string in the form ???*S*???? (like 002_S_0295, 002_S_115, 002_S_0729)

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=_)....S.....(?=_)' file
002_S_0295
002_S_1155
002_S_0729
```

This extracts all characters in between `_`and `_` whose pattern is ????S????? (note 4?S5?, while you say 3?S4?).

> 2.- and the number enclosed between _I and the next underscore (like 241350, 291880, 334105)

Similarly, do use a grep look behind:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=_I)\d+' file
241350
291880
334105
```

Comment: @fedorqui: this is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks!

Comment: You should mention that the `-P` option to grep is GNU-only and, in their words on the man page, `highly experimental` so YMMV with using it. Even if it works it'll be very slow due to the way PCREs are evaluated. Personally I'd avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

With any sed that supports EREs:

```
$ sed -E 's/.*_([^_]+_S_[^_]+).*_I([^_]+).*/\1 \2/' file
002_S_0295 241350
002_S_1155 291880
002_S_0729 334105
```

With any POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's/.*_\([^_]*_S_[^_]*\).*_I\([^_]*\).*/\1 \2/' file
002_S_0295 241350
002_S_1155 291880
002_S_0729 334105
```

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/([^_]+_S_[^_]+).*_I([^_]+)/,a) { print a[1], a[2] }' file
002_S_0295 241350
002_S_1155 291880
002_S_0729 334105
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex in Bash (assuming that is your shell) to do this:

```
while read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do 
    printf "'%s'\n" "$line"
    if [[ "$line" =~ (.{3}_S_.{4}) ]]
    then 
        echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    fi  
    if [[ "$line" =~ _I([0-9]+) ]]
    then
        echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    fi  
    echo
done <file
```

Prints:

```
'ADNI_002_S_0295_MR_MT1__N3m_Br_20110623105302806_S110476_I241350_RightHippoSubfields.mgz.txt'
002_S_0295
241350

'ADNI_002_S_1155_MR_MT1__GradWarp__N3m_Br_20120322164018368_S97230_I291880_RightHippoSubfields.mgz.txt'
002_S_1155
291880

'ADNI_002_S_0729_MR_MT1__N3m_Br_20120913163818876_S159861_I334105_RightHippoSubfields.mgz.txt'
002_S_0729
334105
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[_I]' '{print $3,$4,$5" "$(NF-1)}' OFS=_ file

002_S_0295 241350
002_S_1155 291880
002_S_0729 334105
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with extended pattern matching in Bash – admittedly, it's a bit convoluted:

```
shopt -s extglob

patterns=('???_S_????' '_I+([!_])')

for fname in *.mgz.txt; do
    for pat in "${patterns[@]}"; do
        var=${fname#${fname%$pat*}}
        var=${var%${var##$pat}}
        echo "${var#_I}"
    done
done
```

This uses nested parameter expansions to remove parts of the filenames. Example for the first file and the first pattern:

- Removing part of filename before the pattern:

  - `${fname%$pat*}` expands to `${fname%???_S_????*}`, so it removes everything from the pattern to the end of the name, resulting in `ADNI_`.
  - The result from that is now reused in `${fname#${fname%$pat*}}`, which becomes `${fname#ADNI_}`, which expands to

    ```
    002_S_0295_MR_MT1__N3m_Br_20110623105302806_S110476_I241350_RightHippoSubfields.mgz.txt
    ```

    so `var` now has the part of the filename that starts with the pattern.
- Removing part of filename after the pattern:

  - `${var##$pat}` expands to `${var##???_S_????}`, which removes the pattern from the beginning of the filename. `##` (longest match) is not required for the first pattern, but for the second one<sup>1</sup>: `+([!_])` is "one or more non-underscore characters", and we want the longest match for *that*. The result of this expansion is

    ```
    6_S110476_I241350_RightHippoSubfields.mgz.txt
    ```

    i.e., the part of `var` that we want to remove.
  - `${var%${var##$pat}}` expands to

    ```
    ${var%6_S110476_I241350_RightHippoSubfields.mgz.txt}
    ```

    which removes everything after the pattern.
- Print result: for the first pattern, this is it and we could have printed the second expansion directly, but the second pattern still contains `_I` at this point, so we use

  ```
  echo "${var#_I}"
  ```

  to remove it. For the first pattern, this is a no-op<sup>2</sup>, and for the second pattern it removes the `_I`.

The output of all this is

```
002_S_0295
241350
002_S_0729
334105
002_S_1155
291880
```

---

<sup>1</sup> The `+()` pattern is also the reason that `extglob` is required.

<sup>2</sup> If `???_S_????` happens to match a string that *does* start with `_I`, then this would result in an unwanted removal, but based on the example filenames, it won't.